# How to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-6

I have a Website. Where I need to redirect all the pages from HTTP to HTTPS. But there are two page which should not served over HTTPS.

- Home Page - www.hellomysite.com
- Dealers Page -www.hellomysite.com/dealers

Even if user has entered the url as https://www.hellomysite.com/dealers, it should be served over HTTP. http://www.hellomysite.com/dealers

I googled & found number of links but none of them is redirected.

.htaccess

```
  #Redirect all request to HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.hellomysite\.com*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://hellomysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]


  #RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  on [OR]
  #RewriteRule  ^https://hellomysite.com/dealers$   http://hellomysite/dealers [R=301,L,QSA]
```

If I try anything more, then I get an error on opening the site as

> This website has too many redirects

How do I redirect Home Page & the dealers page to HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you the following code will solve it :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/index\.php [NC]
#the above line will exclude https://www.hellomysite.com/index.php
# from the following rules

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !\/dealers\.php [NC]
# the above line will exclude the https://www.hellomysite.com/dealers.php
# from the following rules

RewriteRule (.+) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
# above line will force every pages and directories ,except those who 
# excluded above and the main root , to redirect from http to https
# (.+) means not to consider http://www.hellomysite.com/ and if you
# change it by  (.*) it will be considered
```

Now you can force entire web site to redirect from http to https except www.hellomysite.com and www.hellomysite.com/dealers.

**Note :** please make sure that you empty browser cache before testing above code

Comment: Nopes.. it redirects every page to HTTP, just FYI I don't have index.php or any page with .php extension. I am using Drupal

Comment: I am using Chrome Icongite window to check all this

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
  #Redirect all request to HTTPS
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
  RewriteRule !^$|dealer https://hellomysite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: no, plus I gets an error. if I enter www.hellomysite.com - 404 Page Not FOund

Comment: Is it 404? make sure the destination url exists.  Try clearing browser caches

Comment: No.
Misconfiguration error in the .htaccess with line number pointing to the rule

Comment: @Aarti The rule I posted works fine on my server. I can redirect all http requests (except root and /dealer) to https .

Comment: I rechecked, it does but due it a long query string is appende in the url of the browser as ~2621934.2876410/htdocs/dev/index.php?q=products

Comment: @Aarti this is probably happening because of other rules. please post your full htaccess.

Comment: Please check this link to access the file http://wikisend.com/download/426648/.htaccess

Comment: @Aarti they are telling me to download the htaccess. Can't you post the code here?

Comment: Its quite big, & its safe to download.